# How to contain a mouseover image link without the new image moving objects above it?

Tags: javascript, css, html, mouseover

What I would like is when the new image loads on mouseover, it does not move any objects above it.  I've tried containing it in a div, but for some reason I cannot get this to work.  Any help or ideas on what I could do?

Here is a page with what it does now:
[click](http://aususrpg.net/testing.php)

And here is my code:

```
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function rollover() {
      if (!document.getElementById) return
      var imgOrSrc;
      var imgPreload = new Array();
      var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
      for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        if (images[i].getAttribute('rsrc')) {
          imgPreload[i] = new Image();
          imgPreload[i].src = images[i].getAttribute('rsrc');
          images[i].onmouseover = function() {
            imgOrSrc = this.getAttribute('src');
            this.setAttribute('src',this.getAttribute('rsrc'))
          }
          images[i].onmouseout = function() {
            this.setAttribute('src',imgOrSrc)
          }
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="rollover()">
    <div id="landimage">
    <a href="linkhere"><img src="/images/braeden.png" rsrc="/images/braeden2.png" border="0"></a>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: nothing is moving really. the two images are different sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply because the images are not of the same dimensions.  The easiest method would be to increase the canvas size of /images/braeden.png and adding a whitespace to the top of it so  it becomes exactly the same height as /images/braeden2.png

If you do not want to to that, then you have to add padding-top to the containing div, when the smaller image is being displayed, to cater for the height difference.